# QJSEngine checkForSyntax function

Tags: c++, qt, qjsengine

In LiScriptEngine we have the following function:-

> QScriptSyntaxCheckResult QScriptEngine::checkSyntax(const QString &
>   program)

which is more useful to identify the type of error occured when engine executes a program.Currently i am migrating from ScriptEngine to JSEngine.But in JSEngine i cannot find real equivalent for this the exvaluate() in JSEngine returns JSValue  in whioch there is no real error object.On going through the docs of JSValue i can see functions like isError() and some properties of error like line,stack,name... but none of this is equivalent to checkForSyntax.Any idea on this problem or this is not possible in JSEngine.